# Sending textbox value to sql database

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, winforms

There is a textbox called tbTodo, which gets information from the database:

```
SELECT `todo` FROM `user` WHERE `username` LIKE '" + _naam + "'";
```

which works. The problem now is, i have no idea how to update the todo list in the database: how to send the textbox value and overwrite the one from the database. Code i have so far (which could be totally wrong):

```
db_connection();
        MySqlCommand cmdRead = new MySqlCommand();
        cmdRead.CommandText = "SELECT `todo` FROM `user` WHERE `username` LIKE '" + _naam + "'";
        cmdRead.Connection = connect;
        MySqlDataReader tdOphalen = cmdRead.ExecuteReader();
        if (tdOphalen.Read())
        {
            tbTodo.Text = tdOphalen.GetString(0);
            connect.Close();
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            connect.Close();
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Well, if you want to update the database, then you'll need to use an `UPDATE` command instead of a `SELECT` command...

Comment: And please look up Command.Parameters.AddWithValue();

Comment: First of all: do NOT use SQL query strings like that unless you want people to perform [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) and harm your database; use a [prepared statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.prepare(v=vs.110).aspx). Second, what is it you are trying to update in the database? I understand it's a todo list but what columns are you trying to update and with what information?

Comment: @Bwolfing For now, it is just a textbox, for a personal project. I have no idea what you mean with prepared statement. I am new to sql. Sorry for my lack of knowlenge, but could you please explain what i should do?

Comment: Take a look at the SQL Injection, prepared statement, and Exploits of a Mom link from @Filburt to understand the dangers of your query first :)

Answer (score 1):

syntax of UPDATE command is

```
UPDATE table_name
SET column1=value1,column2=value2,...
WHERE some_column=some_value;
```

In your case it would be something like

```
"UPDATE `user` set `todo` = '" + tbTodo.Text + "' FROM `user` WHERE `username` LIKE '" + _naam + "'";
```

It should be good for a first try and learn how update values on a database.

Next steps is learn how to use [prepared statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.prepare(v=vs.110).aspx) ;)

Comment: It kinda works? i guess? So i copied your code in my code, and i get an error at line:

     MySqlDataReader tdOphalen = cmdRead.ExecuteReader();

which says:Additional information: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM `user` WHERE `username` LIKE '<name>'' at line 1

Idea how to fix? Btw, sorry for my lack of knowledge, since i am new

Comment: You're using `ExecuteReader` which allows read-only operations. Use `ExecuteNonQuery` instead.